# Regex For Checking Multiple Things Within A String

Tags: c#, regex

I was practicing using regex to make sure a user's input met the required checks  and wrote this section of the code:

```
Regex rgx2 = new Regex("^([A-Za-z0-9])(a{3,6})$");
bool isTrueA = false;

do{
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word with 3 as in it: ");
string p = Console.ReadLine();

    if(rgx2.IsMatch(p))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid a word:");
        isTrueA = true;
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your word is not valid");
        isTrueA = false;
    }

}while(isTrueA == false);
```

So what the code SHOULD do was make sure the user could enter a word with upper and lower case letters as well as numbers, but they had to include 3 'a's in it as well.

However, this isn't working and I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: Use `"^(?=(?:[^a]*a){3,6}[^a]*$)[A-Za-z0-9]*$"`

Comment: Probably better with a string method  like :            Boolean isTrue = p.Select(x => char.IsUpper(x)).Any() && p.Select(x => char.IsLower(x)).Any() && (p.Where(x => x == 'a').Count() >= 3);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single regex pattern, this is the approach I would take, using positive lookahead to assert that there are at least three `a`s or `A`s:

`^(?=(?:.*[Aa].*){3,})[A-Za-z0-9]*$`

In action: https://regex101.com/r/aStQ7L/1

If you need to allow spaces as well, just add a space to the character set at the end:

`^(?=(?:.*[Aa].*){3,})[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$`

Comment: This works quite well, although would there be a way to allow spaces between the characters as well? (Example: C a a a t)?